# Issues with Row and Column Splitter

Tags: sxa-storefront, creative-exchange

We are using SXA Creative Exchange [Sitecore & SXA-9.3]

We are facing issues in SXA Column Splitter while importing the zip

We observed this issue only in Row and Column splitter while other components are working fine with the Creative Exchange

The issues are in vanilla instance itself where only a Column Splitter is added and Exported. Again the same exported Zip is imported without any changes, we get the following error

```
An error occurred while importing a rendering in file: 2020-06-14_18-34_MHO_en_Default_AgencyDrop/test2/index.html
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.RenderingProcessing.StylesImporter.CreateMissingComponentClass(ImportRenderingProcessingArgs args, String parameterName, IEnumerable`1 parameterValues)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.PageProcessing.RenderingParser.Process(ImportPageProcessingArgs args)
```

Comment: I was able to add just the column splitter in a page, export the page and then import it back successfully in SXA 9.3 without any errors. Can you check what you're missing?

Comment: Hey Paul, We have resolved the issue.... i believe your component has got few Css classes selected for each cell in your column splitter rendering properties...

If no css classes are selected, we get null reference error.

The reason for the issue might be the standard values of column splitter/row splitter template does not have any value in Css field list

Comment: Yes, it should be something related css classes, because when I imported the zip package back, Sitecore listed me one change with the css class col-6.. though I didn't add any css class before the export or while I imported back..

Answer (score 0):

If no css classes are selected in the rendering properties of the row/column splitter component, we get null reference error. The reason for the issue is the standard values of column splitter/row splitter template does not have any value in Css field list by default